# Hide "To Email" Address when sending email

Tags: android, email, android-intent

This might be an awkward question.

I am creating an app, for its contact us view. I have a form to send email.

Now either I have to use a Web-service, but I don't have a hosting, so can't use this.

Other option is to use the intent to send email to a specific address, but is it possible to hide the `TO` Email address.

If there is any other option that I can use, please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now either I have to use a Web-service, but I don't have a hosting, so can't use this.

There are many hosting services available, including ones like Amazon AWS that have free levels of use. Please use a Web search engine for `free Web hosting` or similar search terms.

> but is it possible to hide the TO Email address.

No, as that is up to the author of the email client, not you.